# display a selected combobox char appear in given input of rows and columns

Tags: c#

I'm a student and was absent for one meeting so I'm self studying for this topic.
There are 4 activities and this is the last one, but its seems that I'm stuck.

Basically what i want is to display the selected combo box item in the given input number of rows and columns. In my code, it only displays the first row and and first column.

How can I make it display a grid (row x column) of the given character (eg. 4x4, 5x2, 3x4)?

[image: Sample form]

```
int x, y,z;
y = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
z = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
label4.Text = " ";
for (x = 1; x <= y; x++)
{
    label4.Text = label4.Text + comboBox1.Text;
}

for (x = 1; x <= z; x++)

{
    label4.Text = label4.Text + comboBox1.Text + "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong place to ask this question. Google "nested for-loop example" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you better use StringBuilder

```
 int x, y, z;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        y = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        z = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        label4.Text = " ";
        for (x = 1; x <= y; x++)
        {
            sb.Append( label4.Text + comboBox1.Text);
        }
        sb.Append("\n");

        for (x = 1; x <= z; x++)
        {
            sb.Append(label4.Text + comboBox1.Text + "\n");
        }
        label4.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify you second loop :)

```
string line = label4.Text;
// line = "@@@@", now we want to append it three times to Label4 (because first line is already there)
for (x = 1; x < z; x++)
{
    label4.Text += "\n" + line;
}
```

I took example value of lines (rows) to be 4 :) Hope I explained well. Another approach wold be to use nested loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < z; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        label4.Text += comboBox1.Text;
    }
    label4.Text += "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

```
int x = 4;
    int y = 3;
    string s = "@";



   for (int ix = 0; ix < x; ix++)
   {
       label2.Text += s;

    }
    for (int iy = 0; iy < y; iy++)
    {
        label2.Text += s + "\n";
    }
```

if you need all corner:

```
   int y = 4;
        int x = 10;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string s = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 1; i < x + 1; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("@");
        }
        s = sb.ToString() + "\n";

        //Remaining string
        String rStr = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            rStr += s; 
        }

        label2.Text = rStr;
```